# About a theorem on subspace topology from Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> For any metric spaces $Y \subset X$, a subset $E$ of $Y$ is open relative to $Y$ if and only if
> $E = Y \cap G$ for some open subset $G$ of $X$.

There's an analysis book by Grinberg that has a picture related to this theorem in Rudin.

[Here's the pic in question illustrating the theorem above](https://ibb.co/Pgb1MzM)

According to the pic, if $X = \mathbb R^3$, then for any $p \in E$, we can find a suitable $r_p > 0$ to build open three-dimensional balls in the ambient three-dimensional "box" s.t. a union of these balls intersecting a plane $Y$ results in $E$.

Among other things, is the pic assuming $\mathbb R^2 \subset \mathbb R^3$? Also, given $\displaystyle{G = \bigcup_{p\in E}\{q \in X: d(p, q) < r_p\}}$, how can we have a distance from $p$ (a point in $\mathbb R^2$) to $q$(a point in $\mathbb R^3$)?

Comment: No, $p \in \mathbb{R}^3$ in the picture.

Comment: The text of your question doesn't seem to relate to the text in the image. It is standard to consider $\Bbb{R}^2$ as a subset of $\Bbb{R}^3$ via the mapping $(x, y) \mapsto (x, y, 0)$.

Comment: Consider the following screenshot: https://ibb.co/4W4RmnW It refers to the figure 10.3 in the OP: https://ibb.co/Pgb1MzM

Comment: Identifying $\Bbb{R}^2$ with $\Bbb{R}^3$ in the standard way, $d(p, q)$ makes sense for $p \in \Bbb{R}^2$ and $q \in \Bbb{R}^3$.